# Can't find QGIS 3.0 Style Menu

Tags: qgis

Need to resize XY data point symbols based on numbers of sightings in a third column of data. Was fairly staight forward in ArcGIS. Can't figure it at all in QGIS 3.0. Most answers I've seen refer to a graduation tab in the Style Menu in Properties but I can't even locate the style menu shown for earlier versions of the program let alone a Graduation Tab.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the **Style** tab in the `Layer Properties` changed its name to **Symbology**.

Either tab shows `Single symbol` on top of it. Please click on a small black triangle at the far right hand side, to call up **Graduated** option.

**QGIS < 3.0** (e.g. 2.18)

[image]

**QGIS 3.0**

[image]

Comment: Assuming the QGIS 3.0 Change from Style to Symbols, QGIS users manual can help with the rest: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=proportional#proportional-symbol-and-multivariate-analysis

Comment: Amazing how changing 'Style' to 'Symbology' makes googling this so much harder because of the enormous number of sites which referenced 'Style' instead. Never again will I forget `Tools` -> `Anytime` -> `Past year`