# Static traffic visualization for certain streets with the help of historical traffic data in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, classification, road, traffic

The goal is to make a static map highlighting certain streets in a city that usually have high traffic (for example, highways and main roads).

I am using OpenStreetMap for the city. The streets need to be highlighted in various colours, depending on their average yearly traffic.
For instance,

- green colour for low traffic streets
- orange for medium traffic, and
- red for high traffic streets.

I have the data on average yearly traffic for these streets, which I have classified into low, medium and high traffic segments, in MS Excel.

I am new to visualization. I tried to search this online on various platforms but have no luck as of yet. Any suggestions to what I might try/look at will be useful. I am using QGIS 3.2.

Comment: Sumedh, can you please describe the way you store the OpenStreetMap data, is it in a GeoDB, or just shapefiles etc. Have you already joint the data in MS Excel with OpenStreetMap data, did you have any mutual 'id'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Taras. I have stored OSM data as shapefiles, with other layers on it (such as colleges with coordinates). Now I need to highlight some streets whose coordinates I can manage to get.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to colour lines in QGIS according to values in the attribute table? This should be covered in most introductory QGIS tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Spacedman. I will go through the tutorials again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sumedh, I hope you have already merged/connected your road shapefile with Excel data.

And now I expect you to have the road network with the attribute "average yearly traffic" in its Attribute table. Something similar as you can see in the image below, where I do have `"AV_Y_TR"` = "average yearly traffic" values (I used probably wrong dimensions but anyway).

[image: Attribute_table]

Then proceed with the shapefile visualization properties through `Properties > Symbology > Graduated` (alternatively a *Rule-based* symbolization method can be applied).

In this menu, you will be able to play around with visualization properties and classification rules.

For instance, I ended up with such adjustments

[image: Layer_Visualization]

In the end, it should look like this

[image: Final_result]

P.S. indeed this should be covered in most introductory QGIS tutorials, as was mentioned by @Spacedman in his comment.

---

**References:**

- [Documentation QGIS 2.18 | Graduated Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=proportional#graduated-renderer)
- [Documentation QGIS 2.18 | Rule-based Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=proportional#rule-based-renderer)
- [Documentation QGIS 2.18 | 4.3. Lesson: Classification](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html)
- [Styling road maps with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/styling-road-maps-with-qgis)
- [Can't find QGIS 3.0 Style Menu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274333/cant-find-qgis-3-0-style-menu)